# Is there an elegant solution to distinguish between void and non void arguments in a template member function call?

Tags: c++

Having a base class and its specialization for void:

```
#include  <iostream>
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    typedef T result_type;
    result_type get_value() { return result_type(); }
    void process_value(result_type&&) {
        std::cout << "type\n";
    }
};

template <>
struct Base<void>
{
    typedef void result_type;
    void get_value() {};
    void process_value(/*void&&*/) {
        std::cout << "void\n";
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T>
{
    typedef typename Base<T>::result_type result_type;
    // Returning void from a function call is fine.
    result_type get() { return this->get_value(); }
    void invoke() {
        // If T is void: error: invalid use of void expression
        this->process_value(get());
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived<int>().invoke();
    // Trigger a compilation faluure:
    Derived<void>().invoke();
}
```

Is there an elegant solution to distinguish between void and non void arguments in the call of 'process_value' (C++11 is fine) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to substitute some empty class for `void` when it comes to passing the result as an argument. I don't find it very elegant, but it works:

```
#include  <iostream>
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    typedef T result_type;
    result_type eval() { return result_type(); }
    result_type get_value() { return result_type(); }
    void process_value(result_type&&) {
        std::cout << "type\n";
    }
};

template <>
struct Base<void>
{
    struct value_type { };
    typedef void result_type;
    value_type eval() { return value_type{}; }
    void get_value() {};
    void process_value(value_type) {
        std::cout << "void\n";
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T>
{
    typedef typename Base<T>::result_type result_type;
    result_type get() { return this->get_value(); }
    void invoke() {
        this->process_value(this->eval());
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived<int>().invoke();
    Derived<void>().invoke();
}
```

To find something more elegant, I feel you may need to refactor your original problem.

Comment: I fear this answer is the best bet. However, I would make a class (call it) None outside of Base<void> and make that the result_type.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly refactored and using C++11, this is another way to approach the problem:

First, your template specialization and `main()` are both unchanged:

```
template <>
struct Base<void>
{
    typedef void result_type;
    void get_value() {}
    void process_value( void ) {
        std::cout << "void\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived<int>().invoke();
    // Trigger a compilation faluure:
    Derived<void>().invoke();
}
```

The first significant change is in the `Derived` template.

```
template <typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T>
{
    typedef typename Base<T>::result_type result_type;

    void invoke() {
        this->process_value();
    }
};
```

As you can see, I've removed `get()` so that may or may not any longer match your intent.  It seemed that what you were attempting to do was to create a temporary something of type `T` and then interrogate it.  That part is unchanged, but the semantics of it are moved to the `Base` class which uses SFINAE to do the right thing.

I've created a convenience function `is_not_void()` and a templated `Enable_if` (after Stroustrup) to make the code a little easier to read.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_not_void() {
    return !std::is_void<T>::value;
}

template <bool C, typename T>
using Enable_if = typename std::enable_if<C, T>::type;
```

Lastly the revised `Base` code:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    typedef T result_type;

    template <typename U, typename = Enable_if<is_not_void<U>(), U>>
     U get_value() { return U(); }


    template <typename U, typename = Enable_if<is_not_void<U>(), U>>
     void do_process_value( U&&) {
        std::cout << "type\n";
    }

    void process_value() {
        do_process_value(get_value<T>());
    }
};
```

As you can see, the templates have a default second template argument which can only be instantiated if the type is not `void`.  The effect is that they will always be matched for everything other than `void` types but the `void` specialization will be used in the case that the type is `void`.  As you already know, even the declaration of a `void &&` argument will cause the compilation to fail, which is why we can't use `Enable_if` within the argument list of `process_value`.

When run, this code produces:

```
type
void
```